# Flutter precacheImage not working for AssetImage in Android/iOS when support multiple dimensions

Tags: flutter

I have been following posts of people trying to use `precacheImage` to avoid flickering when loading `AssetImage` first time. Some key code below:

```
late Image logo;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  logo = Image.asset("path_to_logo");
}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  precacheImage(logo.image, context);
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

Then later logo is used as a child widget:

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
  logo
...
}
```

I also tried to use `precacheImage` before current page loads in `main.dart` but that didn't do any difference. The image is empty for a brief while when first time loaded and then all content is shifted to correct position once the asset image loads.

Using `sdk: '>=2.19.0-168.0.dev <3.0.0'`

Any ideas what could be wrong?

EDIT:

I found out that since I have support for multiple device pixel ratios, the precaching caches only 1x dimensions because I am using the generic path, but the device can be e.g. using 3x and `ImageCache` also seems to have some internal scale property when it caches images.

This ticket might be about the issue I am facing: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3905

Comment: [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) is an async function (it returns a `Future`) so you have to await when it completes, the docs say: "Returns a Future that will complete when the first image yielded by the ImageProvider is available or failed to load."

Comment: I tried inside main.dart with await and it didn't give any error, but still it doesn't use the cached version in my widget first time, so content jumps